# Choose random string from a few and set it as a variable?

Tags: bash, variable

I have a few strings, and I want to set a variable to one of them, randomly. Say the strings are `test001`, `test002`, `test003` and `test004`.

If I set it like normal I'd obviously do it like this:

```
test=test001
```

But I want it to choose a random one from the for strings I have. I know I could do something like this, which I have done previously, but that was when choosing a random file from a directory:

```
test="$(printf "%s\n" "${teststrings[RANDOM % ${#teststrings[@]}]}")"
```

But in this case I am not sure how to set `testrings`.

Comment: set the teststrings array like this: `teststrings=( test001 test002 test003 test004 )`, then your code will work. To save running in a subshell, `printf -v test "%s\n" "${teststrings[RANDOM % ${#teststrings[@]}]}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
array=(test001 test002 test003 test004) ;
rand_var="${array[RANDOM%${#array[@]}]}";
```

Comment: That method to count how many elements the array has will break if any element contains whitespace, or if there are glob-patterns that match files. Simply use `totalstr=${#array[@]}`.

Comment: You don't need to nest arithmetic expressions: `$(( (RANDOM % totalstr) + 0 ))` will do, but you don't need to add zero: why do you do that?

Comment: Thanks , I d no idea about the array count, that's why ... !

Comment: @glennjackman, array indices are already evaluated as arithmetic expressions, so it's just `rand_var="${array[RANDOM % ${#array[@]}]}"`

Answer (score 1):

Store your strings in an array.

Use [`jot(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jot) to choose an array index at random.

Print the array element at that random index.

Consider this script `foo.sh`:

```
# initialize array a with a few strings
a=("test1" "test2" "test3" "test4" "test5" "test6")

# get the highest index of a (the number of elements minus one)
Na=$((${#a[@]}-1))

# choose:  
#    jot -r 1         1 entry, chosen at random from between
#             0       0 and ...
#               $Na     ... the highest index of a (inclusive)
randomnum=$(jot -r 1 0 $Na)

# index the array based on randomnum:
randomchoice="${a[$randomnum]}"

# display the result:
printf "randomnum is %d\na[randomnum] is '%s'\n" \
    $randomnum "$randomchoice"
```

Output:

```
$ . foo.sh
randomnum is 3
a[randomnum] is 'test4'
$ . foo.sh
randomnum is 0
a[randomnum] is 'test1'
$ . foo.sh
randomnum is 4
a[randomnum] is 'test5'
$ . foo.sh
randomnum is 1
a[randomnum] is 'test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do something similar:

```
v=$(printf "test%03d" $(($RANDOM%4+1)))
v=${!v}
```

where bash `${!variable}` does one level of indirection towards the real variable `test001` etc.

---

When the names of the variables can be anything, eg test001 somevar anothervar, setup an array:

```
declare -a teststrings=(test001 somevar anothervar)
v=${teststrings[$(($RANDOM % ${#teststrings[*]}))]}
w=${!v}
echo $w
```

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunetaly I might have written my question a bit wrong. The strings can be anything, not just the same thing with increasing numbers. Sorry.

Comment: can you put all the variable names in an array?